# New install of Debian 11.3.0 freezes after cryptsetup: set up successfully

Tags: linux, debian, installation, freeze

I installed Debian 11.3.0, upon first boot, it appears to crash right after entering the LUKS password. No oops or kernel panic or other errors or warnings.

The freeze occurs immediately after this:

cryptsetup: sda3_crypt: set up successfully

No more text. The screen remains on. No blinking cursor. Scroll lock, caps lock, num lock, does not work.

There are no terminals available, alt+f2, f3, etc. does not work.

This is a server, there is no X environment that should have attempted to start, I didn't even install the desktop environment packages. Perhaps they get pulled in anyway and it does indeed attempt to start X?

In any case, is this a common issue? Is there a simple fix for it?

Comment: At the grub boot menu avoid automatic boot and edit the boot so there's no "quiet" option anymore in the kernel boot parameters. You can also use the recovery boot in advanced options. You might then see additional information maybe helping to solve the problem. No guarantee.

Comment: @A.B That helped, got it working. Crashed at "switching to inteldrmfb from efi vga", added nomodeset (IIRC this has been an issue on occasion, for almost two decades by now). If you'd like to add an answer specifying this, I'll mark it as right. Thanks!

Comment: Just do yourself the answer to your question with what you did (including the grub part): this will be more acurate.